# Send 3 javascript arrays to c# server side code

Tags: c#, javascript, client

I am fetching an XML format data and assigning it to a treeview. The XML Data has an ID attribute attached to it. On client side I am getting all the selected nodes of the treeview. I am able to fetch the name of the node from the control. Now I want to get that ID attribute so that I can send it as a reference ID. How can I get the ID of the selected nodes in JavaScript?

I am using `DevExpressTreeView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer**

This help to get the id of selected node.